# mysql calling procedure Error Code: 1241. Operand should contain 1 column(s)

Tags: mysql, error-handling

Okey tried to find something that solved my problem but everyone else seem to have this inside the procedure and not when they are calling this. Guess I'm unique..

So I have created this procedure

```
USE `DB`;
DROP procedure IF EXISTS `NAME`;

DELIMITER $$
USE `DB`$$
CREATE PROCEDURE `NAME` (IN arg1 INT,IN arg2 INT, OUT arg3 varchar(10))

BEGIN
    UPDATE T1 SET var1 = arg1 WHERE var2 = arg2 ;
    IF((SELECT var2 FROM T1 WHERE var2 = arg2) IS NOT NULL) THEN
        SET arg3 = "YEAH!!"; 
        COMMIT;
    ELSE 
    SET arg3 = "FAIL!!"; 
        ROLLBACK;
    END IF;
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

And I'm now trying to call for the procedure using this code

```
SET @arg1 = 1, @arg2 = 2;
CALL `DB`.`NAME`(@arg1, @arg2, @arg3);
SELECT @arg3;
```

And i'm getting this error

> Error Code: 1241. Operand should contain 1 column(s)

Would love if someone with a brighter mind than me could explain what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: `CALL NAME.NAME(@arg1, @arg2, @arg3;` this line is full with mistakes. 
your db name is not `NAME` and you must close the parentheses.
`CALL DB.NAME(@arg1, @arg2, @arg3);`

Comment: That was a simple miss when I changed the names so it would be easier to understand for others. Same with the (), it missed when I changed.

Comment: If you found the solution yourself, you should _not_ include it in your *question* but provide an *answer*, which you should also accept then...

Comment: Noted! Will do, thanks for saying :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: Found out what it was! The IF statement shouldn't be surrounded by ()

```
IF (SELECT var2 FROM T1 WHERE var2 = arg2) IS NOT NULL THEN
    SET arg3 = "YEAH!!"; 
    COMMIT;
```

Do this and it will work!